# Using PayPal IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to get details from PayPal IPN and display whether the transaction has been verified or not. I am using the code below and if it is cancelled it shoes as Failed which is correct, but even if the transaction has been successful it is still showing failed. Any ideas where this code is going wrong please

```
    //read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

//post back to PayPal system to validate (replaces old headers)
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
//

//error connecting to paypal
if (!$fp) {
    //
}

//successful connection    
if ($fp) {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        $res = trim($res); //NEW & IMPORTANT

        if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            //insert order into database    
            echo'Success';
        }

        if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            //insert into DB in a table for bad payments for you to process later
            echo'Failed';
        }
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: You really should use the `PayPal PHP Merchant SDK`. It comes with the `paypal / sdk-core-php` which have a built-in [class to check IPN message validity](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/blob/master/lib/ipn/PPIPNMessage.php).

Comment: Many thanks I will have a look. This script is actually provided by PayPal for checking IPN  Typically it is flawed somewhere :)